# TemplateDoesNotExist - file exists, no permissions issue

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm receiving this error when trying to render a template in django:

**TemplateDoesNotExist**

```
...
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
```

Here's my settings.py entry:

```
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'template'),
)
```

Here's my view that's being called:

```
def handler(request):
    if request.method == 'GET': 
        NewAppFormSet = modelformset_factory(Application)

    return render_to_response(request, "template/apps.html",{"new_app_form":NewAppFormSet})
```

I've tried every possible combination of paths, adjusting permissions, etc. The real issue seems to be with the template loaders, as they are not recognizing any paths set forth in TEMPLATE_DIRS. I've hardcoded this string, to no avail. I've also ran `python manage.py runserver` with sudo / as root. I'm at a loss...

Comment: By chance is there an `include` template tag in `apps.html` which references a template that doesn't exist?

Comment: Hmm, I'm extending another template - I went ahead and removed that (as well replaced the entire template with some basic markup), still no luck. Great catch though, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what example I was following that specified the render_to_response shortcut method requires the views' request object to be passed, but it was as easy as changing it to:

```
return render_to_response("template/apps.html",{"new_app_form":NewAppFormSet()})
```

Comment: Might have been following the official docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/ . But the official docs start start with `render`, not `render_to_response`. Which is not necessarily obvious for people who are doing a quick glance to remember the argument order.

Answer (score 5):

I had a very similar issue which was driving me crazy.  It turns out that the book I was using to learn Python/Django did not say that I had to set the templates directory in settings.py expressly.  Very confusing.  I am using Python 2.6 & Django 1.3.1 - maybe a previous version automatically found the templates dir.  Anyway, after pulling my hair out for a day and reading a lot on this site I figured out that I had to replace the default TEMPLATE_DIRS assignment with the following in settings.py:

```
# Find templates in the same folder as settings.py.
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates'),
)
```

**Thanks stackoverflow!!**

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning SETTINGS_PATH with os.path.realpath:

```
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what example I was following that specified the render_to_response shortcut method requires the views' request object to be passed, but it was as easy as changing it to:

`return render_to_response("template/apps.html",{"new_app_form":NewAppFormSet})`

Answer (score 0):

By any chance, you might have copy-pasted the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` you have now, did you leave the default one lower down the `SETTINGS` file?

Answer (score 0):

From my settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

def RELATIVE_PATH(*args):
    return os.path.join(BASE_DIR, *args)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    RELATIVE_PATH('template'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

what if you try

```
return render_to_response(request, "apps.html",{"new_app_form":NewAppFormSet})
```

instead of

```
return render_to_response(request, "template/apps.html",{"new_app_form":NewAppFormSet})
```