# TemplateDoesNotExist at/

Tags: django-templates

here is my site url http://webtrick.heliohost.org/
my template directory settings:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__) , 'templates').replace('\\','/')
)
```

#### view.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Template , Context
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
def index(request):
        return render_to_response('index.html')
```

#### url.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from webtrickster.views import index
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', index)
)
```

i don't know what's wrong with this code 
any help appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__) ,'../templates').replace('\\','/')
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Is it just me, or should there be a single quotation mark before `../templates'` ?

Answer (score 61):

Make sure your Django app is in the INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py. That was my problem with it. So if you have the templates folder in your polls app folder, you need to add the 'polls' at the end of the installed apps in the settings file.

Answer (score 29):

Add you application into setting.py end of the INSTALLED_APPS like below:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mysite'                   
  ]
```

and your templates dir should be in mysite like

```
mysite
    -settings.py
    -templates/
```

Comment: It does not load css files in the templates directory.

Answer (score 10):

I wasted a lot of time trying to figure out what was wrong with my `'templates'` directory and found out that :

You may have forgotten to add `TEMPLATE_DIR` in the following segment of `settings.py` :

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

So it should have `'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],` instead of `'DIRS': [],`

Also see answers for : [TemplateDoesNotExist at /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909010/templatedoesnotexist-at)

Answer (score 5):

First you need to make one folder named 'templates' in your django project folder then, you can add template directory by two ways open your settings file then add any of the following code

1) You can specify your template path directly by

`TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    'D:/Django/web/Kindset/templates' #your file path ,this is my template directory path
)`

2) Or if you want to use generic path means use

`TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    'os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),'
)`

Answer (score 1):

You may forgot to install you app

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tutorials'
]
```

Make sure you also add dirs properly in your templates

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "mysite/templates"
)

[TemplateDoesNotExist - file exists, no permissions issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975842/templatedoesnotexist-file-exists-no-permissions-issue)

Answer (score 0):

My templates folder wasn't a python package because it was missing the __init__.py file.
This might have been the reason why Django was not locating my templates.

Answer (score 0):

Many good answers here, but on updating an old project (nightmare=zinnia, django_cms, AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser') that was not maintained for many moons from django 1.6 to django 1.7 as stage one of a very long process, I found nothing worked. Then I noticed that the errors had quotes around the template it was trying to load:

```
/home/vagrant/venv/crowd88/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_admin_style/templates/'core/includes/ga.html' (File does not exist)
```

So I looked at the source and found that quotes are stripped this way:

```
# lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/utils/plugins.py
...
template = get_template(force_unicode(node.template).strip('"'))
...
```

Then I noticed that single quotes were being used in the loaders

```
{% include core/includes/ga.html' %}
```

So the fix was

```
{% include "core/includes/ga.html" %}
```

using a regex process

Answer (score 0):

Move your "templates" folder to the main and not in any sub folder. Or on the same level as other projects folder. This might have been the reason why Django was not locating my templates.
My project worked after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

make  sure your dirs directory in settings.py looks like this

`'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],`

Answer (score 0):

By default, inside the settings.py file, the '**DIRS**' array is empty as you can see below.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

So to solve the issue, just add *BASE_DIR / 'templates'* to the array to look like below. And you are good to go.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the settings.py file and check the TEMPLATES section. Notice the DIR value, by default it should be []. Add "os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')" inside this. It should look like this :

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. After checking TEMPLATE_DIR and INSTALLED_APPS a thousand times I noticed a small typo in one .html template:

```
{% extends "my_app/base.html " %}
```

should have been

```
{% extends "my_app/base.html" %}
```

(notice the white space in the first command)

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried some of the solutions above and it not worked try checking whether the template is within the correct folder.

Template outside of the `templates/appname` folder:

```
appname/
  |
  |__templates/
  |  |
  |  |__appname/
  |     |__appname_form.html
  |__appname_list.html <------ outside of the appname/ folder (WRONG)
```

Like this if you have a url that send to this template, Django will through a `TemplateDoesNotExist` since the template does not follow the path you placed in `TEMPLATES.DIRS`.

Try fixing like:

Template inside of the `templates/appname` folder:

```
appname/
  |
  |__templates/
  |  |
  |  |__appname/
  |     |__appname_form.html
  |     |__appname_list.html <------ inside of the appname/ folder (RIGHT)
```

Therefore, like this you may fix this exception.

Answer (score 0):

if {% extends "blog/base.html" %} make sure base.html is in the blog folder and not in Templates or any other directory. That solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
1.Make a folder in your app called static and create the css file in the static folder
2.Make another folder still in your app called templates and create the html file there

3. On the first line of your html file write this: {% load static %}
4. Link the css file inside the head tag as follows:  href="{% static 'index.css' %}"
5. Thank me later.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem !
I've already followed all solutions provided above but pfff ! I were lost and maybe someone could face it too!
So I solved it by only
`return render(request, 'profile.html')`
and not
`return redirect(request, "profile.html")`

Happy debugging !!!

Answer (score 0):

After debugging a lot, i found out that the path which i was giving in views.py to render the template is wrong so it was showing **TemplateDoesNotExist at/** error

for Example the mistake i was making is this

Wrong code :-
return render(request, 'show/index.html', {'product_objects': product_objects})

Right code :-
return render(request, 'shop/index.html', {'product_objects': product_objects})

the app name was shop not show.

Hope it will help someone

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is pretty simple just give the right path
Use this if you have your templates folder in your app

```
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
     
    
 'DIRS': [BASE_DIR,"templates"],
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the template folder inside your app.
[Refer this image for directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNZKh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone makes the same stupid mistake. Got similar error when I forgot to enclose included template in quotes, and what is really confusing it highlights a different line in a base template in the error screen. Basically:

```
{% include blog_entry.html with n=i tags=i.tags %}
```

instead of

```
{% include 'blog_entry.html' with n=i tags=i.tags %}
```

see quotes around blog_entry.html

Answer (score -1):

This is the little requirement:

return render(request, 'templetes/test.html')
with
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR) ,'templates'],

NOT
return render(request, 'test.html')