# TemplateDoesNotExist at /. i dont know where i'm wrong

Tags: python, django

I don't know where i'm wrong, i'm fairly new to this so please tell me where i'm wrong.
help me please, this is
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

urls.py

```
"""portfolio URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home)
]
```

path

```
manage.py
db.sqlite3
    views.py
    urls.py
    settings.py
    asgi.py
    wsgi.py
    __init__.py
    templates/home.html
```

i'm using Django 3.0.10

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#configuration

Comment: You need to revise your django project structure. Have you followed the tutorial? You need to create apps... if you want minimal structure then Django is probably not the best choice for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TemplateDoesNotExist at/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686044/templatedoesnotexist-at)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- `BASE_DIR/templates` (option 1)
- `BASE_DIR/APP_DIR/templates/appname` (option 2)

if you are using the `option 1` you have to add it to your `TEMPLATES` settings variables (because `django` does not look for it)

```
TEMPATES = [
    ...
    DIRS: [
        # django >= 3
        BASE_DIR / 'templates',

        # django < 3
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') # add 'import os' to your settings.py
    ]
]
```

then in your view:

```
def view(request):
    # Case 1:
    # assuming your html file `file.html` exists here `BASE_DIR/templates/myapp/file.html`
    # use this
    # return render(request, 'myapp/file.html')

    # Case 2:
    # assuming your html file `file.html` exists here `BASE_DIR/templates/file.html`
    # use this
    # return render(request, 'file.html')

    # Case 3:
    # assuming your html file `file.html` exists here `BASE_DIR/APP_DIR/templates/myapp/file.html`
    # use this
    # return render(request, 'myapp/file.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you create an app for managing views.py? I couldn't get from your code. I think the problem has been created for URL paths.
Try to make an app in the root folders, create views, add in url.py of the app and finally root URL patterns. For more detail, please check: [Django Documantation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/)

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong.

It looks like your path is currently `appName > templates > home.html`

It needs to be `appName > templates > appName > home.html`

So basically, add a new dir in your templates dir and name the new dir the same as whatever you named your app, then save your html files within there.

Edit: It looks like you don't have an app.

You should create an app... cd to your project dir and run `django startapp appName`

Add it to your config in your `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'appname.apps.appNameConfig'
]
```

Then in that app dir do the above ... `appName > templates > appName > home.html`

Comment: He doesn't even have an app....

Comment: @BriseBalloches Thanks, you're right. Have edited.